# Makefile rule to check svnversion result

Tags: svn, makefile, sed

Trying to make a makefile rule to check that svnversion gave a proper result.

Normally, it should return something like one of the following:

```
1023:1055M
1056
```

However, it can get an error like:

```
svn: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'; please get a newer Subversion client
```

So here is my version of the rule based on other posts:

```
test2:
    @if [ $$(svnversion | sed s/[0-9:M]*//g | grep '.') -neq ""];   \
    then                                                            \
          echo >&2 "Unexpected result from 'svnversion'"            \
               "of $$(svnversion)";                                 \
          false;                                                    \
    fi
```

However, the condition seems to trigger on both cases.

Comment: The sh snippet can be reduced to simply: if $(svnversion) | sed s/[0-9:M]*//g | grep . ; then... (not Make protected)

No need to invoke test (or [) at all.

Comment: Based on other posts? If it doesn't work then why not settle the question in those other posts, instead of starting a new one?

Comment: Other one was resolved and worked, this was a new variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I eventually resolved this:

```
test_svnversion_output:
    @if [ $$(svnversion 2>&- | wc | awk '{print $$1}') -eq 0 ];     \
    then                                                            \
        echo >&2 "Error: 'svnversion' produced bad result"          \
             "'$$(svnversion 2>&1)'.";                              \
        false;                                                      \
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you see tells that the 'svnversion' command is from another minor Subversion version than the client you use to update your working copy.

E.g. This happens when you use a TortoiseSVN based on Subversion 1.6.6 with the Subversion 1.5.6 commandline client.

Comment: This is not what is being asked for in this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ! $(subversion) | grep -qE "[0-9]+:[0-9]+M"; then
```

Comment: Note that svnversion can also use S and P in its result, or any combination of these letters.